# See the output of the program started at boot

Tags: terminal, boot, raspbian

I have written a Python script `test.py`.  The script is running continuously and occasionally outputs information.  If the script is started in terminal, I can see the output.

However, I want that the script starts at the boot, so I put

```
sudo python /home/pi/test.py &
```

in `/etc/rc.local`.

After I log in, I cannot see the output.  Is there any way how to "open" the terminal after logging in and see the script's output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have a modern distro with systemd/journald you should be able to see rc.local output in `journalctl -b`.

In Fedora/RHEL 8/CentOS 8 to see only rc-local.service logs you can run:

```
journalctl -f -u rc-local.service
```

No idea how it can be done in Debian/Ubuntu and other distros.

---

Considering your comments you could try this command as well:

```
journalctl -f $(which python)
```

---

P.S. Having `sudo` in `rc.local` makes no sense - everything which is run from `rc.local` is launched under the root account by default.

---

You could redirect the script's output somewhere and by doing so you'll be able to follow it with `tail -f`, e.g. `python /home/pi/test.py >/var/log/test.log 2>&1 &` Then follow the log with `tail -f /var/log/test.log`.

Comment: I see hundreds of lines by this command.  I just need to see script's output, possibly continuously.

Comment: That wasn't in your question like at all. `journalctl -f` will let you see system logs continuously. You could try this as well `journalctl -f $(which python)`

Comment: I am sorry that my question was not clear enough.  I just want to see as I see when started from the terminal.  BTW, your suggestion from the comment shows nothing.

Comment: You could redirect the script's output somewhere and by doing so you'll be able to follow it with `tail -f`, e.g. `python /home/pi/test.py >/var/log/test.log 2>&1 &` Then follow the log with `tail -f /var/log/test.log`.

Comment: OK, it is cumbersome, but it works.+1

Comment: Would you please write this comment as a new reply, or include it in the existing reply, so I could accept it?  Thanks.

Comment: @Pygmalion It's already in the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can redirect STDERR and STDOUT to files, and look at them.

```
python test.py test.out 2>/home/pi/test.err
```

I omit the `sudo` because `/etc/rc.local` is run as `root` already.

Comment: So it is not possible to track the output in real time like in case when script is called from the terminal?